# FaceBook invite friends for Unity AppRequest

Tags: android, unity3d, facebook

При приглашении открывается панель, подгружаются друзья из FaceBook, при отправке сообщения, они не приходят, такая проблема у многих, решения не нахожу, кто-то боролся с этим как-то? Настроено все правильно, советовали использовать Dashboard Branch, не работал с этим сервисом, мануалов толком нету для юнити, установил sdk Branch все ключи настроил, а дальше проблемы с ссылками, есть вариант с https://docs.branch.io/pages/viral/facebook-app-invites/ 
но там примеры кода для iOS - Objective-C |  iOS - Swift 3 | Android - Java, возможно ли под юнити запустить ?

Comment: Подозреваю, что что-то не донастроили. У нас в игре проблем с приглашалкой не было.

Comment: у разработчиков, которые выпустили игру в сентябре, все работало до недавних дней, у других так же

Comment: Они в Октябре изменили кое-какие вещи в API. Вам должно было уведомление прийти.